# Defining models in a top level Django directory

Tags: python, django

I've noticed that in order for me to define models, I need to do something like:

```
python manage.py startapp app_name
```

Is there anyway to avoid this convention and be able to create a models.py directly in the top level site that django-admin.py has created for me? Sometimes I'm building a site that can be put together in literally 15 minutes thanks to Django. I don't see the need for complexity of having an additional app built and a modified settings.py just for a form model or something similar.

Comment: Really? How long does it take to type `python manage.py startapp app_name`?

Comment: And add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`; those seconds add up :)

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  The django admin programs expect `app/models.py` file names.